# Mysql: jumps in data thorugh logging device and how to recalc while do the query

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts, offset

```
+---------------------+--------+--------+
|      Datetime       | Curve1 | Curve2 |
+---------------------+--------+--------+
| 2016-02-10 19:32:00 | -0,048 | -0,033 |
| 2016-02-10 19:33:00 | -0,047 | -0,033 |
| 2016-02-10 19:34:00 | -0,05  | -0,033 |
| 2016-02-10 19:35:00 | -0,047 | -0,033 |
| 2016-02-10 19:36:00 | -0,047 | -0,034 |
| 2016-02-10 19:37:00 | -0,047 | -0,033 |
| 2016-02-10 19:38:00 | -0,052 | -0,032 |
| 2016-02-10 19:39:00 | -0,049 | -0,033 |
| 2016-02-10 19:40:00 | -0,046 | -0,033 |
| 2016-02-10 19:41:00 | -0,045 | -0,033 |
| 2016-02-10 19:42:00 | -0,045 | -0,033 |
| 2016-02-10 19:43:00 | -0,044 | -0,033 |
| 2016-02-10 19:44:00 | -0,048 | -0,032 |
| 2016-02-10 19:45:00 | -0,045 | -0,032 |
| 2016-02-10 19:46:00 | -0,046 | -0,032 |
| 2016-02-10 19:47:00 | -0,045 | -0,032 |
| 2016-02-10 19:48:00 | -0,046 | -0,033 |
| 2016-02-10 19:49:00 | -0,05  | -0,032 |
| 2016-02-10 19:50:00 | -0,076 | -0,001 |
| 2016-02-10 19:51:00 | -0,077 | -0,001 |
| 2016-02-10 19:52:00 | -0,077 | -0,001 |
| 2016-02-10 19:53:00 | -0,076 | -0,001 |
| 2016-02-10 19:54:00 | -0,077 | -0,002 |
| 2016-02-10 19:55:00 | -0,075 | -0,001 |
| 2016-02-10 19:56:00 | -0,074 | -0,001 |
| 2016-02-10 19:57:00 | -0,075 | 0      |
| 2016-02-10 19:58:00 | -0,074 | 0      |
| 2016-02-10 19:59:00 | -0,077 | -0,001 |
| 2016-02-10 20:00:00 | -0,074 | 0,001  |
| 2016-02-10 20:01:00 | -0,074 | 0      |
| 2016-02-10 20:02:00 | -0,074 | 0      |
| 2016-02-10 20:03:00 | -0,073 | 0,001  |
| 2016-02-10 20:04:00 | -0,071 | -0,002 |
| 2016-02-10 20:05:00 | -0,074 | 0,001  |
| 2016-02-10 20:06:00 | -0,074 | 0      |
| 2016-02-10 20:07:00 | -0,074 | 0      |
| 2016-02-10 20:08:00 | -0,073 | 0,001  |
| 2016-02-10 20:09:00 | -0,075 | 0      |
| 2016-02-10 20:10:00 | -0,072 | 0      |
+---------------------+--------+--------+
```

Hi, i have serveral datapoints from a mesurement device which mesure the inclination. Normal value changes are 0,001 - 0,003. Bigger jumps in data comes from the automatic recalibration of the system. Now when iam plotting this data i get these jumps you see in the picture.[Chartgraphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ4BU.png)
How can i precalc this to smooth the line ? I though i can look into the row before and when its over 0,01 diffrence save a offset and adding this to the new row. But this query was running over minutes on 60k datapoints :D. Maybe theres an function in mysql or php but iam not a professional and does not find out a thing for the last 3 days. So i ask here. Sorry for my bad english.... iam from germany and not paying attention in school :-)

Comment: This isn't really a highcharts, or even a php or mysql question. This is a statistical analysis question, and not necessarily a simple one. How to account for this jump depends on a lot of things, and simply "smoothing" the line isn't really an answer.  Example question that needs to be asked: how will you differentiate between a re-calibration and actual shift in results? Also, how do you determine a baseline after re-calibration? How do you determine acceptable results? Etc

Comment: We are keeping the original data, the "smoothed" line ist just for further viewings. Recalibration turn the data in high jumps, that couldn't be a mesurement becaue its out of its range.

Comment: Hmm..  I would go that way: `I though i can look into the row before and when its over 0,01 difference save a offset and adding this to the new row` -> but I would use JavaScript, to use browser, not backend data. Simple loop `for(...) { ... }` should do "the thing".

Comment: I guess I would be concerned about a device for which recalibration returns values that are out of range :) But that aside - it's still very hard to say how to handle this without better understanding the underlying issues, what kind of precision you need in the plotted data, and what kind of baseline or reference the data can be compared to that makes sense across these jumps.